# Find function by 2 tangents and 2 points

Tags: systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, interpolation

I am looking for explicit function descriptions $F_1(s)$ and $F_2(s)$, following the line plotted. The line is just a description, but $F_1$ should never exceed $F_m$ and start at $s_0$ with a tangent of $dF_0$.

[image: Function]

$F(s) = \left\lbrace \begin{matrix}
dF_0\cdot s   & 0 \leq s < s_0 \\
F_1(s) & s_0 \leq s < s_m \\
F_2(s) & s_m \leq s < s_s \\
F_s    & s \geq s_s
\end{matrix} \right.$

Both $F$ and $\dfrac{dF}{ds}$ need to be continious, such that for $F_1(s)$ at $s_0$:

$F_1(s_0) = dF_0 \cdot s_0$

$\dfrac{dF_1(s_0)}{ds} = dF_0$

at $s_m$:

$F_1(s_m) = F_m$

$\dfrac{dF_1(s_m)}{ds} = 0$

$F_2(s_m) = F_m$

$\dfrac{dF_2(s_m)}{ds} = 0$

and at $s_s$:

$F_2(s_s) = F_s$

$\dfrac{dF_2(s_s)}{ds} = 0$

For $F_1$ I've tried to use quadratic and cubic polynomials and a sine, but without any clear result.

Edit:

The actual values are:

$s_0     = 0.015;$

$dF_0    = 120\cdot 10^3;$

$s_m     = 0.11;$

$F_m     = 4.4\cdot 10^3;$

$s_s     = 0.5;$

$F_s     = 4.25\cdot 10^3;$

Comment: You can use cubic Hermite spline for that.

Comment: @uranix I'm trying that in matlab, using [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28944-hermite-cubic-interpolating-polynomial-with-specified-derivatives/content/pchipd/pchipd.m), however, it seems that F_m is exceeded

Comment: can you please provide us with actual values for $s_0, s_M, s_S$ and corresponding $F$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know both values and derivatives at each node, it is a [Hermite interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation) problem.

The simplest solution to the problem can be obtained using [cubic Hermite spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline). Note, we are using spline, i.e. a piecewise-polynomial function, not a single polynomial.
$$
F(x) = \begin{cases}
dF_0 \cdot s, & 0 \leq s < s_0\\
F_2(s), & s_0 \leq s < s_m\\
F_3(s), & s_m \leq s < s_s\\
F_s, & s \geq s_s
\end{cases}
$$
Let 
$$
F_2(s_0 + (s_m - s_0) t) = f_2(t)\\
F_3(s_m + (s_s - s_m) t) = f_3(t).
$$
Such parametrization rescales each interval into $t \in [0, 1]$. We have
$$
f_2(0) = s_0 dF_0, \quad f_2(1) = F_m, \quad f_2'(0) = (s_m - s_0) dF_0, \quad f_2'(1) = 0\\
f_3(0) = F_m, \quad f_3(1) = F_s, \quad f_3'(0) = 0, \quad f_3'(1) = 0\\
$$
From the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline) a cubic Hermite spline is given as
$$
g(t) = (2t^3 -3t^2 + 1)g(0) + (3t^2 - 2t^3) g(1)
+ (t^3 - 2t^2 + t) g'(0) + (t^3 - t^2) g'(1).
$$
Thus
$$
f_2(t) = (2t^3 -3t^2 + 1)s_0 dF_0 + (3t^2 - 2t^3)F_m + (t^3 - 2t^2 + t) (s_m - s_0) dF_0\\
f_3(t) = (2t^3 -3t^2 + 1)F_m + (3t^2 - 2t^3) F_s
$$

Doing so, we end with the following spline (and it's not what you want)
[image]

The function $f_2(t)$ overshoots and we want it to be monotone.

Let's interpolate $f_2(t)$ but using another function. Recall that $f_2'(1) = 0$. Thus I've picked the following function
$$
f_2(t) = a + b - b \cosh k (t - 1).
$$
It has three parameters $a, b, k$, should be enough to satisfy three conditions. Also this function is monotone.
$$
f_2(1) = a = F_m\\
f_2(0) = a + b - b \cosh k = s_0 dF_0\\
f_2'(0) = b k \sinh k = (s_m - s_0)dF_0.
$$
Eliminating $a, b$
$$
a = F_m, b = \frac{F_m - s_0 dF_0}{\cosh k - 1}
$$
we obtain equation for $k$:
$$
\frac{F_m - s_0 dF_0}{\cosh k - 1} k \sin k =(s_m - s_0) dF_0
$$
Solving it numerically gives
$$
k \approx 4.2628397074
$$

Now the approximating function looks better
[image]